# Comparing regression outputs for different response variables

Tags: regression, bayesian

I have inherited some legacy code designed to solve the following problem - we are given a set of observable binary variables $Y_1, \dots , Y_N$ that we believe are related to a fixed set of input variables $X_1 ,\dots , X_M$ (N.B. high dimension, $M \sim 100$).  For a given input we want to predict which event $Y_i$ is the most likely.

The current program tries to predict this as follows - given training data, we build a model for each $Y_i$ seperately (using logistic regression + feature selection).  Then given an input we look at all of the logit scores and choose the highest.

This doesn't work because some of the logistic regression classifiers can be overtrained, which leads to extreme logit scores which often dominate the other scores.  Analysis reveals that the logistic function may not be a good choice either.

I have two questions :

- is this way of finding the most likely event sensible / salvagable?  I would rather not have to rebuild this whole thing from scratch if possible.
- if so, is there a more sensible way to compare the scores from two classifiers in such a way that it is more fair?  My thoughts are that we could compare some sort of Bayesian posteriori to get a fair evaluation for our state of knowledge, but I feel like if I were to do this I would have to lose the logistic regression model, and I am not sure what I should replace it with.

Comment: It's not clear to me why there are two classifiers being used. If data in are in the format `y_i | x_i1 x_i2 ... x_i100` then what is the justification for using one model to predict a `0` case and another model to predict a `1` case? If there is none, then we can start talking about using just one model and avoiding over-fitting through shrinkage, selection, cross-validation, etc. while using an appropriate validation measure to ensure that the probabilities are well calibrated.

Comment: Sorry I think my description was not clear enough, hopefully it is now.  We are not training on the same output variable twice.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, but I'm still confused.. for the prediction step, are you only choosing one of the $Y_{j=1 \dots N}$? You say 'want to predict which event(s)' which implies that you potentially care about multiple $Y_j$, but then you say that you 'look at all of the logit scores and choose the highest' which implies that you only want the most likely $Y_j$.

Comment: OK, for simplicity, let's just go with the top event, but in practice, I'm interested in the top few.

Comment: In the case that you just want to look at distinct events (just one $Y_j$), then a [multinomial logistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) model might be appropriate and would probably be the easiest to fit/work with.. but in the case where more than one $Y_j$ will occur it is NOT appropriate: you would not be able to train your model nor would it give you meaningful predictions because it could not consider the multiple $Y_j$ cases.

Comment: I don't know anything about the nature of the data, but perhaps a [nested logit](http://elsa.berkeley.edu/eml/qca_reader/7a.nested.pdf) might be appropriate? I've +1ed your question because I'm interested in a solution for your "in practice" case.

Comment: Yeah I get that.  More than one event can occur, so the multinomial is not appropriate.  The idea is to train the classifiers seperately (like 300 of them!) and take the event which gives the highest logistic score.  I don't know whether that is a good idea or not.

Comment: [Multi-label classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) might be the right tool for the job.. one possible method from that category is the multiple battery binary classifiers you are currently using. One thing you might consider is how you are validating your models/avoiding overfitting, which there is a lot of information about on this site and elsewhere. I suspect the only way to answer your specific question is to have the data at hand and try and compare/validate various models.

Comment: You could look into regularization